# Javascript newbie - deal with DRY issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please point me out a direction about how to shorten this code, if possible ?

```
if($(".row-member0").is(":visible")){
    if($("#TeamMember_0_name").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_0_email").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_0_phone").val()==="")i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_0_birthdate").val()==="") i=false;
    if( !validateEmail($("#TeamMember_0_email").val())) { 
        i=false;
    }    
}

if($(".row-member1").is(":visible")) {
    if($("#TeamMember_1_name").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_1_email").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_1_phone").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_1_birthdate").val()==="") i=false;
    if( !validateEmail($("#TeamMember_1_email").val())) { 
            i=false;
    }
}

if($(".row-member2").is(":visible")) {
    if($("#TeamMember_2_name").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_2_email").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_2_phone").val()==="") i=false;
    if($("#TeamMember_2_birthdate").val()==="") i=false;
    if( !validateEmail($("#TeamMember_2_email").val())) { 
        i=false;
    }
}
```

I understand that an interaction should be used perhaps. Just not sure how.

I though about:

**1) Place a .row-member class on top elements and then:**

```
$('.row-member input').each(
    function(index, value) {
        if($(this).val()==="") i=false; 
    }
);
```

Can I have some help plz ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [StartsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector along with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over your class:

```
$("[class^='row-member']").each(function(index) {
    if($("#TeamMember_" + index + "_name").val()==="" || $("#TeamMember_" + index + "_email").val()==="" || $("#TeamMember_" + index + "_phone").val()==="" || $("#TeamMember_" + index + "_birthdate").val()==="" ||  !validateEmail($("#TeamMember_" + index + "_email").val())) { 
        i=false;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Finally, someone providing an answer that uses jQuery each and advanced selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a common class instead of unique classes. That's what IDs are for.

If you do that, then it can be shortened like this:

```
i = $(".row-member:visible input").toArray()
                                  .every(function(el) {
                                       return el.value !== "";
                                   });
```

You'll need a patch for `.every()`.

---

If you don't want to patch `.every()`, then you can do it with just jQuery like this:

```
$(".row-member:visible input").each(function(_, el) {
                                        if (el.value === "") {
                                            i = false;
                                            return false; // to short circuit 
                                        }
                                    });
```

---

Or, presuming that `i` starts off `true`, you can do this:

```
$(".row-member:visible input").each(function(_, el) {
                                        return i = (el.value !== "");
                                    });
```

---

All of these three techniques provide short circuiting, so that you don't need to keep testing values after your first empty value has been found.

Comment: I market your question as very useful. Please keep it as well for consideration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".row-member0").is(":visible")){
    if($("#TeamMember_0_name").val()==="" || $("#TeamMember_0_email").val()==="" || $("#TeamMember_0_phone").val()==="" || $("#TeamMember_0_birthdate").val()==="" ||  !validateEmail($("#TeamMember_0_email").val())) { 
        i=false;
    }    
}
```

Do the same for rest

Comment: That's smaller, yes, but not DRY. If you repeat that for the other two then you're repeating yourself.